# What do the City Border colors signify?

Tags: simcity-2013

In a region I can see each city has a border outline, some are green, yellow, blue, black and my own is white. What are these colors for? Is there a master-list somewhere?

The Manual doesn't list them at all.

Comment: Are you sure that you have looked in the entire manuel?

Comment: The manual is pretty minimal http://www.simcity.com/en_US/manual

Comment: @Elarys Hey, in general you don't need to add in the title of the game to the question, since the tags on the question alone would make that clear

Comment: @Yi Understood, just didn't want it confused with previous versions, though at the moment they are probably all about the new version anyway. ^_^

Comment: @Elarys Well, I don't think there's any room for confusion - we have [simcity-4], [simcity-3000], [simcity-2000] and even [simcity-social] (ewwww). The only possible point of confusion is if someone wanted to ask a question about the original 1989 SimCity, and I'd say the chances of that is *pretty* slim.

Comment: And that tag would be `simcity-classic`, anyway, since that's what it's known / sold as, these days.

Answer (score 7):

Looking around various regions, and seeing the 'blue' borders suddenly gone now, I believe I have figured out what they mean:

- White = You are the Mayor
- Black = Mayor is offline
- Green = Mayor is online and in this city
- Yellow = Mayor is online, but in different city

At launch, there were some colored blue, but that may have been a bug perhaps with server issues.